# Disk Format showing RAW

Tags: hard-drive, format, raw

i have 2 External disks ( 2 TB each) i formatted them on windows 7 laptop then after that i put them on the Accounting server ( windows server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition SP2) first they didn't show in my computer so i assigned drive letters to them so now both Hard disks show in disk management as NTFS but in my computer they show as RAW should i worry about that or no ?
***i can write to the disk normally.

Thank you

Comment: Are the disks formated in GPT or MBR? This article may be worth checking (hotfix to add large disk support to Windows 2003) [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919117)

Comment: thank you for answering, i dont know i pressed properties and volumes but it didnt show if it is formatted as MBR OR GPT

Comment: I would be careful using them for any unique data until you resolve this. Maybe put on back on the laptop to check the disk type?

Comment: they are both empty now still didnt back up any data would you suggest i format them on the server ( EXFAT) ? without taking any risks?

Comment: If they are empty then, yes, I would reformat on the 2003 server using NTFS, but be aware of the limit of 2TB on this OS (see above KB). Use DISKPART and make sure that you change the 'partition style' if it is not MBR.

Comment: i cant format on the server ntfs it only shows exfat

Comment: Did you use DISKPART first? See this similar question: (http://superuser.com/questions/301189/windows-server-2003-wont-let-me-reformat-a-2tb-usb-drive)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26789/discussion-between-user2652374-and-daniel-k).

Comment: is it ok to just format it as EXFAT or will it be a problem , i cant seem to know howt o move this thread to chat if you agree

Comment: i put as per the link you gave me convert it gave the following message : Drive R: is already NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel's help, I just removed both HDDS and then reinserted them. They gave the correct format.

It seems that after giving them drive letters you need to remove them first, then insert.

Comment: I guess people didn't want to see this as an answer / solution to the problem, which it definitely is. You could've also asked David to post the solution himself, but it's fine this way, too.